# How define inequal constraints in MATLAB optimization toolbox?

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

As mentioned in MATLAB R2016 we have this form: `A*x ≤ b` in optimization toolbox constraints. How can I define something lkie this: `A*x < b` in constraints?

Answer (score 2):

Polyhedron `{x: A*x < b}` is no longer a closed set, so if you need to find max/min of a function over this set it may not belong to this set, but suprimum/infimum always exists and for example for linear (in fact, any convex) objective function it's the same as max/min over `{x:A*x ≤ b}`, check [Weierstrass extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem). One option is to set some tolerance t and optimize over `A*x ≤ b-t` and use [sensitivity analysis](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjvs4-47erMAhUmGZoKHcppCI0QFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmat.gsia.cmu.edu%2Fclasses%2FQUANT%2FNOTES%2Fchap8.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE1_t_mP92f1GzDltfsi2fVJIBgWw&bvm=bv.122448493,d.bGg) to see where the solution goes as `t -> 0`.

Answer (score 1):

As @serge_k said, if you have a strict inequality constraint, you want to represent it as `A*x <= b - t` to force at least `t` separation. There are some situations where this reasonably comes up (eg. support vector machines solve `a'x+b >= 1` and `a'x +b <= -1' instead of`a'x+b > 0`and`a'x +b < 0'

That said, the vast vast majority of the time, strict vs. non-strict inequalities really shouldn't matter. If your constraint is `A*x<b` and `A*x <= b` won't do, you may be in the land of pure math rather than numerical computing: floating point operations aren't this precise!

There aren't many plausible, real world situation where `A*x - b = 10^-99999` is wonderful, but `A*x - b = 0` is 100% wrong?

Comment: Check this link for a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364741/matlab-genetic-algorithm-optimization-returns-integer-values-higher-than-boundar . How can I overcome this problem?